# Unable to insert multiple data into MYSQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am unable to insert the data entered in the text box into MYSQL database. I am trying to insert inputs from multiple textboxes into the database.

```
<?php
include('questionDB.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $questionID = $_POST['id'];
    $answer = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['answer']));
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers(question_id, answer_body) VALUES ($questionID, $answer)");
}
?>

<form name="auctionQuestion" method="post">
<?php
    $auctionSurvey = "SELECT question_id, survey_id, question_body FROM questions
                      WHERE survey_id='1'";
    $aucResult = mysql_query($auctionSurvey) or die (mysql_error());
    while($auctionRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($aucResult)){
        echo $auctionRow['question_body']. "<input type=\"text\" name=\"answer\"><BR>";
    ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $auctionRow['question_id'] ?>">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Won't fix your problem, but it seems like you'll be overwriting your column with `WHERE survey_id='1'` - `INSERT INTO answers(survey_id` - `VALUES('1'`

Comment: Which part "doesn't work", and how?

Comment: +1 for using `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Also what @Fred-ii- said.

Comment: `mysql_escape_string_for_real` is getting +1'ed these days? It's a few years past 2001 ..

Comment: @DaSourcerer You do realize that `$questionID` is still open to sql injection, right?

Comment: @jeroen I do. Still, it's a start.

Comment: @DaSourcerer Might have been 10 years ago :-)

Comment: Also you need to quote your html markup here - `echo $auctionRow['question_body'] . "<input type=text name=answer[1][]><BR>"`  More like `echo $auctionRow['question_body'] . '<input type="text" name="answer[1][]"><BR>'` - and what the heck is `answer[1][]` supposed to be?

Comment: @jeroen Ah well. A start is a start. It shows he's at least aware of the problem. There's hope! Show some optimism, man! ;)

Comment: Something else that doesn't fit `INSERT INTO answers` --- `$auctionSurvey = "SELECT... FROM questions`

Comment: Oh I have changed my code. I am still having a problem inserting data into my database.

Comment: Try using `VALUES ('$questionID', '$answer')` or `VALUES ('" . $questionID . "', '" . $answer . "')` instead of `VALUES ($questionID, $answer)` see if that makes it kick in. @user3103739

Comment: So, any luck? @user3103739

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey , thank you so much. I tried with VALUES ('" . $questionID . "', '" . $answer . "') and it worked.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll make it an answer then, so we can properly close the question. @user3103739 (Another Happy Ending) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either:

```
VALUES ('$questionID', '$answer')
```

or:

```
VALUES ('" . $questionID . "', '" . $answer . "')
```

instead of `VALUES ($questionID, $answer)`

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to generate the correct HTML, so that you will get back arrays of variables. 
I think it will be something like this

```
echo $auctionRow['question_body'] . "<input type=\"text\" name=\"answer[]\"><BR>";
```

Similar for the other fields.

Then, when you get the post in, use print_r($_POST) to see exactly what you have got. Go from there.

Comment: I have changed my codes [ edited post ] . I am still having problem inserting the data. The insert query doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do as Fred-ii- suggested.